# A seemingly-complicated question about derivatives and continuity.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

**Question :**

[image]

My problem lies in *the last question*. I think I have managed to solve (a), (b), and (c). I got $$f(0)=f'(0)=A=g'(0)=0$$ and $$g'(x)=f'(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}x\right)-\frac{f(x)\cos\left(\frac{1}x\right)}{x^2}$$ as my answers, if I am correct.

While for the last one I am quite confused. I think I have to follow the definition of being continuous, that is, showing that $$\lim_{x\to0^+}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}g'(x)=g'(0)=0$$ and same for $f'(x)$.

However I can't really see why this is related to the value of $L$. And I bumped into a lot of obstacles while attempting to solve it. For example, how should I deal with $\sin\left(\frac{1}x\right)$ and $\cos\left(\frac{1}x\right)$? Should I apply Squeeze Theorem?

Any hints or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The limit of $g'(x)$ only exists if L is 0. Otherwise it will oscillate because of $cos(\frac{1}{x})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Show $f'(x) \sin(1/x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. (Hint: $|\sin(1/x)| \le 1$.)
- Thus $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} \cos(1/x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. If $L$ is not zero, then $\frac{f(x)}{x^2} \cos(1/x)$ will oscillate between [near] $-L$ to [near] $L$. If $L=0$, then all is well.

Comment: Got it. Didn't realize it was this simple. Thanks!